# How to make a full-sized image scrollable horizontally and vertically just like a map

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to make an image scrollable horizontally, vertically, zoom-able, and allow me place markers on the image. Really, it's just like Google Map, but instead it's an infographic image.

I have tried to place it in two scroll views, which was answered here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2962. I tried it, but it doesn't work.

```
<ScrollView>
  <ScrollView horizontal>
    <image horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" src="~/assets/images/body.png" stretch="aspectFull"/>
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

`aspectFull` allow me to show the actual resolution of the image, however it only allows me to scroll vertically.

In summary, I want to make it to behave just like Google Map, but using an image instead.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have vertical and horizontal scroll bars? Or scroll by dragging the mouse like in google maps?

Comment: Nested ScrollViews needs a different way of implementation on respective platforms, if I'm not wrong you are looking for something like [Image Zoom](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-image-zoom) plugin which allows user to pinch / zoom and move around the image.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work just to satisfy my questions in bare minimum. However, the result is not very desirable as it limits user to scroll only in one direction at a time (eg. you won't be able to scroll diagonally.) Anyway, that would be another question, so here's the answer:

```
<ScrollView  orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView  orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView width="823" orientation="horizontal">
            <ScrollView width="823" orientation="horizontal">
                <image loadMode="async" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" src="~/assets/images/body.png" stretch="aspectFull"/>
            </ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Note: The width of the inner scrollview is set to be the same as the image's width.